# What was the earliest equal temperament system used?

Tags: history, temperament

What was the earliest equal temperament system used?

I believe it to be [19edo,](https://en.xen.wiki/w/19edo) used by  [Guillaume Costeley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guillaume_Costeley) in [Seigneur Dieu ta pitié](https://en.xen.wiki/w/Seigneur_Dieu_ta_piti%C3%A9), in 1558. Was any equal temperament used before then?

7edo is stated in many places to be used in Thai traditional music, but I can't find any evidence of that.

Don't count any piece that only uses octaves (since one-tone equal temperament is dumb).

Comment: It was recognized fairly early on that the large and small tones of just intonation comprise roughly 9 and 8 commas, respectively, and that the semitones can be three, four, or five of these commas, and that the commas are midway in size between the syntonic comma and the Pythagorean comma (which are already very close in size).  This leads to 53-tone equal temperament, but whether or to what extent that knowledge was used, I do not know, and I don't remember whether that was before or after 1558.  I think it was probably in the 1600s.

Comment: @phoog The [Wikipedia page on 53EDO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/53_equal_temperament) suggests that it was studied in antiquity, but it doesn't appear to have been put into wide practice until it was adopted in Ottoman classical music.

Comment: @Theodore I've definitely seen a 16th or 17th century treatise, Italian I think, that talks about this ninefold division of the major semitone.  The extent to which that knowledge was put into practice is another matter.  Most keyboards were being tuned in meantone tuning in those days, where the whole point is that you _don't_ have two sizes of whole tone.  There were some Renaissance or early modern experiments with insane numbers of divisions of the octave, but they definitely were not put into wide practice, whether or not they were meantone systems.

Comment: @phoog Don't you mean major tone?

Comment: You might look into fretted instruments in the Renaissance.  My long-held assumption that equal temperament was a relatively new idea in the time of Bach (enabling the Well-Tempered Clavier to be written in all keys, for instance) has turned out to be false.  Apparently lutes (etc.) were tuned in equal temperament long before then out of necessity.  But I haven't done research enough to post an answer.

Comment: @mathlander yes, I meant to say "major tone."

Comment: @nuggethead I don't think it's quite as simple as that.  Frets _can_ be set at an angle and/or irregularly, and unlike guitar frets they can easily be adjusted when tuning the instrument. some sort of unequal meantone temperament seems more likely.  But all of this ignores the question of what criteria we can use to judge whether a given system constitutes an equal temperament.  In particular, don't think they were using irrational nth roots of two.  How close an approximation of equal will we accept as equal?

Comment: Would a qualitative instruction to "flatten all the fifths ever so slightly so there's no wolf, and get over the fact that the major thirds are too wide" count?  Would a meantone keyboard with 19 or 31 pitches per octave count as 19- or 31-tone equal temperament even if the pitches are defined using rational numbers?

Comment: @phoog It won't count unless they are specifically nth roots of two. All the steps have to be absolutely equal, but since it is impossible to get that level of precision, there needs to be a written instruction saying that all steps are equal, which is the case in Seigneur Dieu ta pitié. A qualitative instruction like the one you mentioned would count if it specifically states that all fifths must be absolutely equal. Even if no such instruction was written, if it was meant to follow a standard equal temperament system at the time (which I don't think existed before 12TET), it would count.

Comment: Also, dividing an interval other than the octave into equal parts using irrational ratios won't count, since this is basically what meantone systems are doing.

Comment: @mathlander "It won't count unless they are specifically nth roots of two": when did mathematics develop the tools to express "nth roots of two"?  By that criterion no system developed before then could qualify.  Meantone systems were not mathematically precise, at least not until 12-tone equal temperament was described as such. "Which I don't think existed at the time": if you add to the system that I described above the criterion "...and make sure all the fifths are equal" then that _is_ twelve-tone equal temperament.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of 7 February 2023, there is no credible evidence in browser searches on Google (including Google Scholar) that equal temperament of any kind was used previously to 1558, nor is there evidence that 7edo was used in Thai traditional music. There may be something in a print book or a letter tucked away in some music library, but it hasn't been scanned yet.